# Greatest integer function inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Prove: $$\Big{[}{n\over 2}\Big{]} +\Big{[}{n\over 3}\Big{]} + \Big{[}{n\over 4}\Big{]}>n$$ for every $n>a$, where $a$ is a natural number
Find $a$.
$[n]$ is greatest integer function

Comment: Assume for every natural number $n>a$: $$[n/2] +[n/3] + [n/4]>n,$$
where $[.]$ is greatest integer function. Find $a$.

Comment: Your question is more than a bit lacking in context. Therefore it started attracting negative attention. Did you read [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) before posting? Highly recommended!

Comment: Here is a hint allowing you to show partial progress. Can you prove that
$$\left[\frac n4\right]\ge\frac{n-3}4?$$ Do a similar estimate for the other terms.

Comment: But I mentioned that a is a natural number, not n

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch:

Note that $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor = n/2$ or $(n-1)/2$.

And $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor = n/3$ or $(n-1)/3$ or $(n-2)/3.$

And $\lfloor n/4 \rfloor = n/4$ or $(n-1)/4$ or $(n-2)/4$ or $(n-3)/4.$

So the smallest case for the left side is

$$\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{n-2}{3}+\frac{n-3}{4} >n.$$

This reduces to $n>27$, so now you know that $a\leq 27$.  So you can work your way down by trying $26, 25, \ldots$ in the inequality until you find an exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer to your Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1oPK.png)

Please find the answer to your problem here.

Comment: There is an error at the bottom of the page you referenced. It should be $\lfloor n/m\rfloor \leq  n/m$. What you need is $\lfloor n/m\rfloor > \frac{n}{m}-1$

Comment: The edited question is wrong